# RDS aroura MySQL upgrade form 5.7 to 8.0 CONFIGURATION_ERROR

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I'm Trying to upgrade aroura MySQL upgrade form 5.7 to 8.0, but got a CONFIGURATION_ERROR

```
{
            "id": "removedSysLogVars",
            "title": "Removed system variables for error logging to the system log configuration",
            "status": "CONFIGURATION_ERROR",
            "description": "To run this check requires full path to MySQL server configuration file to be specified at 'configPath' key of options dictionary",
            "documentationLink": "https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/8.0/en/news-8-0-13.html#mysqld-8-0-13-logging"
}
```

what could be the solution?